# How Can I implement a cordova app for iOS that receive push notification using onesignal

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I am developing a Cordova application using HTML and Javascript (Not Ionic). I need the app to receive the push notification.

I used OneSignal Cordova Push Notification Plugin to implement the push notification functionality. https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-cordova-plugin

I followed the same steps mentioned in one signal to implement the push notification in Cordova https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup

For android, I'm getting the notification without any issues but for iPhone, I'm not getting any push notification. I followed the steps as mentioned in the onesignal documentation like how to upload the apple cirtificate, other settings that I need to make in the app, etc.

When opening the app on the iPhone it is not asking for notification permission too.

Is there anything that I'm missing to implement? or is the plugin correctly working for iOS?